# PySpark Relate multiple rows

Tags: pyspark

I have a problem where I need to relate rows to each other. I have tried many things but I am now completly stuck. I have tried partitioning, lag, groupbys but nothing works.

The rows below the ID 26 wil relate to the MPAN  of 26

```
ID | MPAN     | Value
--------------------- 
26 | 12345678 | Hello  
27 | 99900234 | Bye  
30 | 77563820 | Help  
33 | 89898937 | Stuck  
26 | 54877273 | Need a genius 
29 | 54645643 | So close  
30 | 22222222 | Thanks

e.g.
ID | MPAN     | Value    | Relation 
----------------------------------------
26 | 12345678 | Hello    | NULL 
27 | 99900234 | Bye      | 12345678  
30 | 77563820 | Help     | 12345678 
33 | 89898937 | Stuck    | 12345678  
26 | 54877273 | Genius   | NULL 
29 | 54645643 | So close | 54877273  
30 | 22222222 | Thanks   | 54877273
```

This code below only works for previous row and not the LAG for the 26 record

```
df = spark.read.load('abfss://Files/', format='parquet')
df = df.withColumn("identity", F.monotonically_increasing_id())
win = Window.orderBy("identity")
condition = F.col("Prop_0") != '026'  
df = df.withColumn("FlagY", F.when(condition, mpanlookup))
df.show()
```

Comment: how do you keep the order? imagine, I mix up your lines. How do I retrieve the order you're showing currently ?

Comment: I am going on the basis that the files are imported in the correct order

Comment: nope. That's not how Spark works. It is a distributed system. You cannot maintain that order like in Pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you need a column to maintain the order. In your example, you used [`monotonically_increasing_id`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id) to create that "ordering" column, but that is absurd because

> The function is non-deterministic because its result depends on partition IDs.

Assuming you have a proper "ordering" column :

```py
df.show()
+---+---+--------+-------------+                                                
|idx| ID|    MPAN|        Value|
+---+---+--------+-------------+
|  1| 26|12345678|Hello        |
|  2| 27|99900234|Bye          |
|  3| 30|77563820|Help         |
|  4| 33|89898937|Stuck        |
|  5| 26|54877273|Need a genius|
|  6| 29|54645643|So close     |
|  7| 30|22222222|Thanks       |
+---+---+--------+-------------+
```

you can simply do that with [`last`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.last) function :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window


df.withColumn(
    "Relation",
    F.last(F.when(F.col("ID") == 26, F.col("MPAN")), ignorenulls=True).over(
        Window.orderBy("idx")
    ),
).show()

+---+---+--------+-------------+--------+
|idx| ID|    MPAN|        Value|Relation|
+---+---+--------+-------------+--------+
|  1| 26|12345678|Hello        |12345678|
|  2| 27|99900234|Bye          |12345678|
|  3| 30|77563820|Help         |12345678|
|  4| 33|89898937|Stuck        |12345678|
|  5| 26|54877273|Need a genius|54877273|
|  6| 29|54645643|So close     |54877273|
|  7| 30|22222222|Thanks       |54877273|
+---+---+--------+-------------+--------+
```

Comment: That's brilliant this works a treat. Thanks you